# Horizontal stacked angular bar charts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am trying to implement an Angular horizontal stacked bar chart- Something like [this example](https://codepen.io/jamiecalder/pen/NrROeB).

However, I want just one bar that is stacked.

I am working with AngularJS and Chart.js. I have the example showing on the page.

In the PieController, ChartData contains:

```
 {"data":["63","38"],"labels":["Ford","GM"]}
```

In the example, instead of the label on the outside, I would like the label and then the number to be inside the chart. Like [=====Ford 63====|===GM 38===] the equals represent bar colors. There will be more data points than the current two.

Here is my page

```
<div ng-controller="PieController">
            data {{ChartData}}   //testing purposes
            <div ng-init="getBarChart()">
            <canvas id="Chart1"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript controller

```
app.controller('PieController', function($scope, ChartService) {


$scope.getBarChart = function(){
    ChartService.get({name: 'main'}, function(data) {
        $scope.ChartData = data;

        var barOptions_stacked = {
            tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },
            hover: {
                animationDuration: 0
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif",
                        fontSize: 11
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    gridLines: {},
                    stacked: true
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        color: "#fff",
                        zeroLineColor: "#fff",
                        zeroLineWidth: 0
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif",
                        fontSize: 11
                    },
                    stacked: true
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            },

            animation: {
                onComplete: function () {
                    var chartInstance = this.chart;
                    var ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                    ctx.textAlign = "left";
                    ctx.font = "9px Open Sans";
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";


                    Chart.helpers.each(this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                        var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                        Chart.helpers.each(meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                            data = dataset.data[index];
                            if (i == 0) {
                                ctx.fillText(data, 50, bar._model.y + 4);
                            } else {
                                ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x - 25, bar._model.y + 4);
                            }
                        }), this)
                    }), this);
                }
            },
            pointLabelFontFamily: "Quadon Extra Bold",
            scaleFontFamily: "Quadon Extra Bold",
        };

        var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart1");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'horizontalBar',
            data: {
                labels: ["2014", "2013", "2012", "2011"],

                datasets: [{
                    data: [727, 589, 537, 543, 574],
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(63,103,126,1)",
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(50,90,100,1)"
                }, {
                    data: [238, 553, 746, 884, 903],
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(163,103,126,1)",
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(140,85,100,1)"
                }, {
                    data: [1238, 553, 746, 884, 903],
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(63,203,226,1)",
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(46,185,235,1)"
                }]
            },

            options: barOptions_stacked,
        })

    });//end chat service.get
}

});
```

Instead of hard coding in the dataset which is what its doing now, is there a way I can use the data "ChartData" that I outlined in the beginning of the post?

I'm not sure how to do it or if its even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the label to show in the bar, reference the *labels* property of `$scope.ChartData`:

```
ctx.fillText($scope.ChartData.labels[index] +" "+ data, 50, bar._model.y + 4);
```

> Instead of hard coding in the dataset which is what its doing now, is there a way I can use the data "ChartData" that I outlined in the beginning of the post?

Use properties from the *data* variable (supplied by the ChartService get function) i.e. `data.labels` and `data.data` instead of the hard-coded values.

So update the labels line from:

```
labels: ["2014", "2013", "2012", "2011"],
```

To this:

```
labels: data.labels,
```

And similarly for the datasets:

```
datasets: [{
    data: data.data,
```

So when creating the Chart it should look like this:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: data.labels,
        datasets: [{
            data: data.data,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(63,103,126,1)",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(50,90,100,1)"
        }]
    },

    options: barOptions_stacked,
});
```

Expand the code snippet below for a demonstration.

<sub>Note: there is currently an issue with the resize-listener, blocked by a CORS issue -  I am trying to find a way to disable that.</sub>

#### Update:

Per your comment about stacking the bars (horizontally) - yes that is possible. Just have one element in the *datasets* array for each item. One simple way to have this is to use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) to create an array similar to the example:

```
var bgColors = [
    "rgba(63,103,126,1)",
    "rgba(50,90,100,1)"
];
var hoverBgColors = [
    "rgba(50,90,100,1)",
    "rgba(140,85,100,1)"
];
var datasets = data.data.map(function(value, index) {
    return {
      data: [value],
      backgroundColor: bgColors[index],
      hoverBackgroundColor: hoverBgColors[index]
    }
});
```

Then use variable *datasets* when creating the Chart object:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: data.labels,
        datasets: datasets
    },
    options: barOptions_stacked,
});
```

Also, there is some weird math going on for the location of the second label but the helper function can be updated like below (I tried dividing the *x* value by 75 but that may need to be adjusted - I am not sure what "appropriate" values are for that ...):

```
if (i == 0) {
    ctx.fillText($scope.ChartData.labels[i] + " " + data, 50, bar._model.y + 4);
} else {
    ctx.fillText($scope.ChartData.labels[i] + " " + data, (bar._model.x - 25) / 75, bar._model.y + 4);
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory('ChartService', function() {
  return { //dummy chart service
    get: function(obj, callback) {
      var data = {
        "data": ["63", "38"],
        "labels": ["Ford", "GM"]
      };
      callback(data);
    }
  };
});
app.controller('PieController', function($scope, ChartService) {
  $scope.getBarChart = function() {
    ChartService.get({
      name: 'main'
    }, function(data) {
      $scope.ChartData = data;
      var barOptions_stacked = {
        tooltips: {
          enabled: false
        },
        hover: {
          animationDuration: 0
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif",
              fontSize: 11
            },
            scaleLabel: {
              display: false
            },
            gridLines: {},
            stacked: true
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: false,
              color: "#fff",
              zeroLineColor: "#fff",
              zeroLineWidth: 0
            },
            ticks: {
              fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif",
              fontSize: 11
            },
            stacked: true
          }]
        },
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        animation: {
          onComplete: function() {
            var chartInstance = this.chart;
            var ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
            ctx.textAlign = "left";
            ctx.font = "9px Open Sans";
            ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";

            Chart.helpers.each(this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
              var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
              Chart.helpers.each(meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
                data = dataset.data[index];
                if (i == 0) {
                  ctx.fillText($scope.ChartData.labels[i] + " " + data, 50, bar._model.y + 4);
                } else {
                  ctx.fillText($scope.ChartData.labels[i] + " " + data, (bar._model.x - 25) / 75, bar._model.y + 4);
                }
              }), this)
            }), this);
          }
        },
        pointLabelFontFamily: "Quadon Extra Bold",
        scaleFontFamily: "Quadon Extra Bold",
      };

      var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart1");
      var bgColors = [
        "rgba(63,103,126,1)",
        "rgba(50,90,100,1)"
      ];
      var hoverBgColors = [
        "rgba(50,90,100,1)",
        "rgba(140,85,100,1)"
      ];
      var datasets = data.data.map(function(value, index) {
        return {
          data: [value],
          backgroundColor: bgColors[index],
          hoverBackgroundColor: hoverBgColors[index]
        }
      });
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
          //use empty labels because the labels are on the bars
          labels: data.labels.map(function() {
            return '';
          }),
          datasets: datasets
        },
        options: barOptions_stacked,
      })
    }); //end chat service.get
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PieController">
  data {{ChartData}} //testing purposes
  <div ng-init="getBarChart()">
    <canvas id="Chart1"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is good, and thank you for the thought out reply, but is there a way to get them stacked? like GM 38 right after ford 63 on the same line? That was also what i wanted

Comment: Also, setting the labels to nothing is in red. It works, but that line plus everything below it is in red.  labels: data.labels.map(()=>''),

Comment: Okay see my updated answer. And when you say "_setting the labels to nothing is in red_" I presume you mean your IDE reports that code as an error. That is likely because it is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), part of the [ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) specification, which the IDE might not be configured for... Anyway, I converted it back to a regular function to return an empty string `labels: data.labels.map(function() { return '';})`

Comment: Let me implement this and get back to you.

Comment: For some reason i am seeing the labels and data over lapped in the first bar. I ran your code snippet and see yours is not doing that, so not sure why mine is. The stacked bar is working perfectly

Comment: One potential problem i see is with the labels and data in each bar. The data will shrink and grow. So, for example we have 2 data points. In reality i will have close to 10. Is there a way to rectify this?

Comment: Im sorry its probobly asking too much out of you. You have already went above and beyond. Your answer is outstanding and has helped me so much. I plan on selecting it as the answer. Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: is there a way to move the labels to the outside of each bar? and just have the data inside?

Comment: Hmm... I would say leave the labels out of the bar and use the regular label but then IDK how that would work with the subsequent bars... where should the label go?

Comment: I was just wondering if having the label infront of each bar would help line up the data. Like Ford |== 63==| GM |== 38 ==|  the equals are the bars

Comment: Even having the labels below each bar would work too

Comment: Yeah you could add the labels below by adding to the _y_ values (e.g. y+50) but then you would need to likely draw a rectangle with a bg color (other than white) or change the text color from white to a darker color so the text would be visible...